# How to prevent screenshot from program

Tags: c#, winforms, onkeypress, keypreview

Is there a way to protect a program from any form of screenshoting by users? For example I do not want my program to be in a screenshot when user presses Print Screen key on the keyboard. Is it possible to make somehow a key preview in the program that minimizes the program on pressing Print Screen keyt by user?

I want this for C# WinForms.

P.S. I know it is a bit stupid, user can take a real photo of the screen :P but just my curiosity!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only thing that I could think of right now would be using a [video overlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_overlay) to draw the application's contents (i.e. similar to classiv video players). That way usual screenshot programs will just get a blank/almost black image. But it's still no 100 % secure way. Everything that passes through software can be manipulated/grabbed in some way.

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of any way to prevent a determined application from capturing your app's screen output.  The screen can be captured by a lot more than just the PrintScreen key.  In Windows, just about any app can read the entire screen device surface by reading from DC handle zero.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to stop screenshots.

Comment: Although `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` makes it more difficult.

Comment: @RaymondChen You lazy bugger - won't even link to your own blog posts. Let me sicophantically do so for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/03/10422964.aspx

Comment: @x0n First, SO frowns upon links to offsite pages. Second, I don't have a time machine. (How could a comment from 2012 liink to a blog post from 2013?)

Comment: @x0n Didn't mean it as a scolding. Just explaining. Sorry.