# How does outlook disable screenshot

Tags: java, c++, windows, outlook, operating-system

Outlook has an email encryption function. Emails with this feature turned on will not be able to be screenshotted. When the recipient takes a screenshot of this email, the screenshot result is a black screen.

I searched for ways to take screenshots on Windows, and the [bitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) function was called. There is nothing special about this function. I want to know how Outlook controls the screenshot software to be unable to take screenshots, because it cannot decide how other software calls this function, nor can it modify the calling parameters. How the code is implemented?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions and satisfy my curiosity.
:)

I'm a Java programmer and can read basic c++ code, describing the logic in pseudo-code is fine.

Comment: Microsoft wrote Outlook. Microsoft wrote Windows. Microsoft has internal APIs that they do not share publicly. Get a job at Microsoft. Then you can use those internal APIs. Hope that helps!

Comment: "i want to write either c++ or java code" does not make this a quesiton about c++ and java. I would even say its not a quesiton about programming but about how windows works. Before you can write a program you need to know what that program should do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent screenshot from program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554018/how-to-prevent-screenshot-from-program)

Comment: https://github.com/akinbicer/screen-capture-protector <- or code I found by following the hints in the linked post

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not sure if that is the case.  Chrome does the same thing when you try and take a screenshot of something on prime video.  Looks like using hardware acceleration might be the root cause: https://www.theverge.com/23715928/netflix-amazon-prime-screenshot-mac-windows-how-to

Comment: I am not sure how they do it, but you might try a global windows message hook and filter out the printscreen keypresses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks

Comment: @NathanOliver Hardware accelerated email viewing! Give us all the spam. Now!

Comment: Even if you cannot take a screenshot from the computer, you can still use your phone to take a photo of the "secure" email.

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130603-00/?p=4193